# Many Mouses keeps locking/sticking, eventually "USB device unrecogonised"

Tags: windows-7, usb, mouse

I am having a terrible problem with mice.

A brand new mouse may work perfectly for maybe 24-48 hours and then start locking up and "stuttering". Eventually the problem becomes worse, either locking up completely or stuttering so often they become unusable.

In the worst cases, I recieve a "USB device unrecogonised" error ... but then after a re-plug that same device can work again (and keep working perfectly for maybe 24 hours or 2.4 seconds ....then the cycle re-cycles)...but there seems to be no logic..... *except* these failures *seem* too occur during higher CPU load...)

I now have a good selection of "faulty" mouses:

- Micrososft "OEM" optical x 3
- Logitech Laser Rx1500
- Logitech Laser 442?
- Some VERY cheap chinese thing

I have tried plugging them into my direct MoBo USB ports, Mobo + Powered USB hub etc - nothing seems to change.

I have completely removed (I think) all mouse oriented driver software and re-installed from Windows 7 disk.. but EVERYTING seems to be to no avail!

All other USB devices seem to be working 100% fine .. I have two external HDs (Icy Box) - my headset is a USB device and for them NO PROBLEMS ... its just these effin mices!

- OS: Windows 7 x64 Ultimate 6.1.7600 (fully updated)
- MoBo: Gigabyte P35C-DS3R
- CPU: Intel Core2 Duo E4500
- BIOS: Award F4, 07/09/2007
- RAM: 4G Crucial

Any help or suggestions would be very welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does anything similar happen to other USB devices?  Particularly ones that are plugged in and then used consistently.

Comment: No all other devices are good. I have 2x external HDs and a Logitech headset attached ... no prblems with those at all ....  It really is just the mice!

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your power supply is insufficient, even if it's labelled as having adequate wattage.

It may just be producing dirty power and should be replaced; unfortunately it's not easy to test power supplies.